# Retrieve a value from XML using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Can anyone please help me to retrieve a value `<QuoteId>` from the attached XML file using T-SQL and XQuery?

I am trying to use this T-SQL but no luck

```
declare @QuoteResponse XML
select @QuoteResponse =gQuoteResponse FROM AutoRenew where policyid= '454544'

SELECT b.value('(OverallResultStatus)[1]', 'varchar(100)')  as status
FROM
@QuoteResponse.nodes('GetQuoteResponse/OperationResult') as a(b)
```

This is I am using to retrieve the `QuoteId`

```
DECLARE @QuoteResponse XML

SELECT @QuoteResponse = gQuoteResponse FROM [dbo].[AutoRenew] WHERE policyid = '454544'

SELECT
    @QuoteResponse.value('(GetQuoteResponse/QuoteResults/QuoteResult/QuoteId)[1]', 'bigint')
```

Thanks

```
<GetQuoteResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OperationResult>
    <OverallResultStatus>xxxx</OverallResultStatus>
    <Results>
      <Result>
        <ResultStatus>xxxx</ResultStatus>
        <ResultCode>ddf</ResultCode>
        <ResultMessage>xxxxx</ResultMessage>
      </Result>
    </Results>
  </OperationResult>
  <QuoteResults>
    <QuoteResult>
      <OperationResult>
        <OverallResultStatus>xxx</OverallResultStatus>
        <Results>
          <Result>
            <ResultStatus>xx</ResultStatus>
            <ResultCode>xxxx</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessage>xx</ResultMessage>
          </Result>
        </Results>
      </OperationResult>
      <MainData>
        <StartDate>2012-08-14T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <ReturnDate>2013-08-13T00:00:00</ReturnDate>
        <TripType>xxx</TripType>
        <Area>xxx</Area>
        <Relationship>Individual</Relationship>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>xxx</ProductId>
          <Name>xxxx</Name>
        </Product>
        <Endorsements>
          <Endorsement>
            <EndorsementCode>xx</EndorsementCode>
            <Selected>xx</Selected>
            <Name>xxx</Name>
          </Endorsement>
          <Endorsement>
            <EndorsementCode>xxx</EndorsementCode>
            <Selected>xxx</Selected>
            <Name>xxxx</Name>
          </Endorsement>
        </Endorsements>
        <Promotion>
          <PromotionCode />
        </Promotion>
        <Travellers>
          <Traveller requestedMedicalScreening="false">
            <TravellerId>xxxx</TravellerId>
            <Title>xxx</Title>
            <FirstName>xxx </FirstName>
            <LastName>xxxx</LastName>
            <Age>xxx</Age>
          </Traveller>
        </Travellers>
      </MainData>
      <Price>
        <NetToParentAgent>xxx</NetToParentAgent>
        <NetPrice>xxx</NetPrice>
        <Tax>edew</Tax>
        <GrossPriceWithAllSurchargesAndMedicalScreenings>103.02</GrossPriceWithAllSurchargesAndMedicalScreenings>
      </Price>
      <QuoteId>322423234</QuoteId>
      <QuoteExpiryDate>xxx</QuoteExpiryDate>
      <SummaryOfCover />
    </QuoteResult>
  </QuoteResults>
</GetQuoteResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @QuoteResponse XML
SELECT @QuoteResponse = gQuoteResponse FROM dbo.AutoRenew WHERE policyid = '454544'

SELECT
    @QuoteResponse.value('(/GetQuoteResponse/QuoteResults/QuoteResult/QuoteId)[1]', 'bigint')
```

You just need to follow down the XML element hierarchy - until you read your desired value:

```
<GetQuoteResponse     -- this one is relevant ....
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OperationResult>  -- irrelvant - not in here.....
    ......
  </OperationResult>
  <QuoteResults>       -- this one is relevant ....
    <QuoteResult>      -- this one is relevant ....
      <OperationResult>  -- irrelvant - not in here..... 
        ....
      </OperationResult>
      <MainData>   -- irrelvant - not in here..... 
        ......
      </MainData>
      <Price>    -- irrelvant - not in here..... 
        ......
      </Price>
      <QuoteId>322423234</QuoteId>   -- here's our value !
```

Comment: Still no luck. it is returning null value.

Comment: @user740022: then your XML must look different - this code works just fine when I run it. Can you check your XML again?

Comment: Yes, I did check it . There are no change in the XML file. I am using the same XML file. But still returning null value. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @user740022: can you show the **exact and complete** T-SQL statement(s) you're using? Please update your question by editing it - thanks!

Comment: @user740022: [see this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2af52/1) - it reproduces your table and XML exactly - and if you run it, you **do get** the proper value from `<QuoteId>`. There **must be** something that's different in your database ....

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yeah, my XML file was containing the default namespace and that was the problem. Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a temp table then populating the temp table using openxml?

```
DECLARE @QuoteResponse XML
SELECT @QuoteResponse =gQuoteResponse FROM AutoRenew where policyid= '454544'

DECLARE @idoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @QuoteResponse

CREATE TABLE #QuoteIds(   
    [QuoteId] VARCHAR (10))

INSERT INTO #QuoteIds ([QuoteId])
    SELECT QuoteId
    FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/QuoteResults/QuoteResult/QuoteId', 2) WITH #QuoteIds

DECLARE @quoteid VARCHAR (10)
SET @quoteid = (SELECT TOP 1 QuoteId FROM #QuoteIds)
```